# How do I make a dot disappear after being eaten?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am attempting to program a python game using turtle-graphics, and I've run into some obstacles. When I run my code it allows me to direct the turtle around, then a whole bunch of dots start appearing, and then it has recursion depth error.

The section of code that I am having issues with is this:

```
def move():
    colormode(255)
    global turtle
    global moving
    x = randomColor()

    if moving:
        for i in range(1):
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.shape('turtle')
            turtle.shapesize(.5, .5, .5)
            turtle.color(x)
            turtle.forward(5)
            ontimer(move, 10 // FRAMES_PER_SECOND)

        x = randrange(-250, 250)
        y = randrange(-250, 250)
        pen1 = Pen()
        pen1.hideturtle()
        pen1.penup()
        pen1.goto(x, y)

        pen1.dot(10, "red")

        if turtle.pos() == pen1.pos():
            pen1.clear()
            pen1.goto(x, y)
```

How can I fix this? I want the dot to disappear when the turtle goes over it, and then a new random dot to generate, only one dot at a time.

Answer (score 0):

you should:

1. Draw red point once on start and save the coordination.
2. After each move check the turtle position with your last_point (x,y).
3. If same, draw a dot in the same position with color of background(white I think).

   3.1. Then create new random x,y and redraw the red dot.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd go about this is to define a second turtle with the shape and color of the food.  Then stamp that turtle to generate food, keeping the result of the `stamp()` call so you can call `clearstamp(stamp)` on it later.  I've set such up below with lots of food which the turtle chases down until they're all gone:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randrange

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500
FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 24
TARGET_SIZE = 10

POSITION, STAMP = 0, 1

def move():
    global meal

    x, y = meal[POSITION]
    tx, ty = turtle.position()

    if x - TARGET_SIZE // 2 < tx < x + TARGET_SIZE // 2 and y - TARGET_SIZE // 2 < ty < y + TARGET_SIZE // 2:
        food.clearstamp(meal[STAMP])

        if meals:
            meal = meals.pop()
        else:
            meal = None

    if meal:
        turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(meal[POSITION]))
        turtle.forward(turtle.speed())
        screen.ontimer(move, 1000 // FRAMES_PER_SECOND)


screen = Screen()
screen.setup(int(WIDTH * 1.1), int(HEIGHT * 1.1))  # size window but leave a border

turtle = Turtle(shape='turtle')
turtle.speed("fast")
turtle.penup()

food = Turtle(shape="circle", visible=False)
food.shapesize(0.5, 0.5)
food.color("red")
food.penup()

meals = []

for _ in range(10):
    x = randrange(-WIDTH // 2, WIDTH // 2)
    y = randrange(-HEIGHT // 2, HEIGHT // 2)

    food.goto(x, y)
    meals.append(((x, y), food.stamp()))

meal = meals.pop()

screen.ontimer(move, 1000 // FRAMES_PER_SECOND)

screen.exitonclick()
```

This turtle just chase a random bit of food, you can modify the code to make him go after the nearest food (as you have the list of meals with their positions) or take control of the turtle yourself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do:
(name).up()
(name).forward(10000)

Comment: Any chance you can give a little more context to make your answer a little clearer?